# R function to find and return value in different row of dataset

Tags: r

I have a dataset of about 200k rows. "Column1" is a unique identifier in "data". "Column2" has an identifier that it should look for. And the last column is "Price" which is a numeric value. I would like to create a new column called "Price2" that looks at "Column2" value and searches the whole dataset for that value in "Column1". Once it finds that value it returns "Price" from that row and puts it into "Price2" of the original row.
Any idea how I can achieve this in R?

I only found ways to do this if these were 2 different datasets using merge or inner_join.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We may use `match` to get the index where 'Column2' values are matching in 'Column1' and use that to retrive the corresponding 'Price' and assign it to 'Price2' column

```
df1$Price2 <- with(df1, Price[match(Column2, Column1)])
```